# How to drop all tables in db2

Tags: sql, db2, sql-drop

I want to drop all tables in db2 database with foregin keys, without drop and recreating.

Comment: well, presumably the same way as you upvoted the previous 3 times, plus accept some more answers (if they helped you).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you also want to drop all views, indexes, foreign keys, etc.:

```
select 'drop index "' || TRIM(INDSCHEMA) || '"."' || TRIM(INDNAME) || '";'
  from SYSCAT.INDEXES
  where UNIQUERULE = 'D'
  and INDSCHEMA = (select current schema from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1);

select 'alter table "' || TRIM(TABSCHEMA) || '"."' || TRIM(TABNAME) || '" drop foreign key "' || TRIM(CONSTNAME) || '";'
  from SYSCAT.TABCONST
  where TYPE = 'F'
  and TABSCHEMA = (select current schema from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)

select 'alter table "' || TRIM(TABSCHEMA) || '"."' || TRIM(TABNAME) || '" drop unique "' || TRIM(INDNAME) || '";'
  from SYSCAT.INDEXES
  where UNIQUERULE = 'U'
  and INDSCHEMA = (select current schema from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1);

select 'alter table "' || TRIM(TABSCHEMA) || '"."' || TRIM(TABNAME) || '" drop primary key;'
  from SYSCAT.INDEXES
  where UNIQUERULE = 'P'
  and INDSCHEMA = (select current schema from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1);

select 'drop table "' || TRIM(TABSCHEMA) || '"."' || TRIM(TABNAME) || '";'
  from SYSCAT.TABLES
  where TYPE = 'T'
  and TABSCHEMA = (select current schema from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1);

select 'drop view "' || TRIM(TABSCHEMA) || '"."' || TRIM(TABNAME) || '";'
  from SYSCAT.TABLES
  where TYPE = 'V'
  and TABSCHEMA = (select current schema from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1);
```

Comment: At first thought it is not working BUT The selects written above generates code which then needs to be executed (and then works) :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you are in Linux or Unix enviroment.

```
#!/bin/ksh

## load profile of your instance owner

db2 "connect to <db_name">
db2 -x "select tabschema,tabname from syscat.tables where type='T' and tabschema not like 'SYS%' with ur"|while read a b

do
   db2 "load from /dev/null of del replace into $a.$b nonrecoverable"
done

return 0
```

This script delete the data into the tables.

Answer (score 2):

```
db2 "Select 'DROP TABLE ', tabname, ';' from syscat.tables where owner='DBUSER'" >> filename
```

Delete the very first line and last line of the file and run it using,

```
db2 -tvf filename.
```

This way we can also save the log of tables we have dropped.

PS: Make sure once, only the tables you wanted are present in the file. Dont by mistake, drop some system tables.